# how can I display tooltip or item information on mouse over?

Tags: html, mouseover

I am displaying 5 `userImage` on one screen.I want to display `userID` and  `email` on `mouseover` on those userImage.I used `alt` property of image control but that not working in mozila,chrome and some versions of IE.
So what are the other better ways to display info on mouseover?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use the **[`title`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp)** attribute while `alt` is important for SEO stuff.

Comment: Your title link is not useable in this problem.

Comment: ALT's main importance is for accessibility to people with vision impairments.

Comment: @Super, it is importnat actually, have a look at : http://www.seoworkers.com/seo-articles-tutorials/alt-attribute.html

Comment: @sarfraz does `title` work in mozila nd chrome nd all versions?

Comment: @nectar: yes it works there too but you should be worried about browsers being used now by the masses.

Comment: but it displays all info in one line only what if - <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="a cat" title="My cat <br> sat on a table" />

Comment: @nectar: That's how it will display, you can not control that or split it otherwise you will have to use some other fancy tooltip that you can search on google.

Answer (score 34):

The simplest way to get tooltips in most browsers is to set some text in the [title attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp).

eg.

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" alt="a cat" title="My cat sat on a table" />
```

produces (hover your mouse over the image):

[a cat http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1275939952008633500.jpg](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1275939952008633500.jpg)

Title attributes can be applied to most HTML elements.

Comment: but it displays all info in one line only what if -
    <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="a cat" title="My cat <br> sat on a table" />

Comment: @nectar: you cannot insert line breaks using this method - you have to leave it to the browser to insert line breaks where it thinks most appropriate.

Answer (score 12):

The [`title` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) works on most HTML tags and is widely supported by modern browsers.

Comment: but it displays all info in one line only what if - <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="a cat" title="My cat <br> sat on a table" />